# Flutter - Dialog start new Activity

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am developing an app that is counting points, after the teams have been created. After the teams are created, an AlertDialog pops up and displays the names. Then it should be possible to click on a button to open a new activity. That activity should not be connected to the previous activity. Does anybody has an idea, how this could be done?

Here is the code-snippet of the dialog activity:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'punktezaehler.dart';

class Team_Dialog extends StatefulWidget{

  final List<String> team_namen;

  Team_Dialog(this.team_namen);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _TeamDialogState(team_namen);

}

class _TeamDialogState extends State<Team_Dialog>{

  final List<String> team_namen;
  _TeamDialogState(this.team_namen);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new ListBody(
            children: List.generate(1, (index){
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Team 1: ", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Roboto")),
                      Text(team_namen[0] + " und " + team_namen[1])
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Team 2: "),
                      Text(team_namen[2] + " und " + team_namen[3])
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              );
            })
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            splashColor: Colors.red[900],
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: new Text("Abort", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
        ),
        new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shuffle),
            onPressed: (){
              shuffle(team_namen);
              setState(() {
              });
            }
        ),
        new FlatButton(
            color: Colors.green,
            splashColor: Colors.green[800],
            onPressed: () => , //After click it should start new Activity
            child: new Text("Start Game", style: TextStyle(color:  Colors.white))
        )
      ],
    );
  }



  List shuffle(List items) {
    var random = new Random();

    for (var i = items.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

      var n = random.nextInt(i + 1);

      var temp = items[i];
      items[i] = items[n];
      items[n] = temp;
    }

    return items;
  }


}
```

It would be awesome if someone has an idea :D

Comment: Could you write the code when you call to the dialog and where you can receive the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually when you are talking about Flutter think about pages, not activities.  It should be something like :

```
Navigator.push(context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),);
```

SecondScreen is another widget with its own  Widget build(BuildContext context) method where you will declare what to have on this page.

In case you want to return back, you can do it with:

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
```

Source [documentation](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/)

You can also use named routes for navigation. Example:

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In our case, the app will start
  // on the FirstScreen Widget
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When we navigate to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen Widget
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // When we navigate to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen Widget
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

And something like:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
```

[Documentation](https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/named-routes/)

Comment: But is it possible to delete the "Back"-Button on the new screen, so that i can make a custom one?

Comment: Yes you can, you can use whatever you want, the only limitation is to hang it on an action like onPressed and ect.

Comment: I found it out by myself, but thanks for your advice. The only thing i had to do is to add inside Appbar: "automaticallyImplyLeading: false";

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to use `Navigator.push()` or `Navigator.pushNamed()` and then remove the back button. Because the page that you are leaving from will remain in the pages stack.

What you actually should use is `Navigator.pushReplacement()` **if you don't want the user to be able to go back to the previous page**.

And if you are doing it from a dialog, you should **pop** the dialog **first** and then **push** the next page.

Comment: Why it isn't good practice to hold stack of visited pages in your app ? What are potention problems here ?  Actually I look up and there are some problems with animation and flicking back icon on appbar when you use Navigator.pushReplacement().

Comment: If you don't need a page anymore (i.e. if you don't want the user to be able to go back to the previous screen), you should use the pushReplacement function. It takes the current page off the navigation stack and pushes your new page. An example would be when your user logs in to your app, you show the main screen of your app after logging in, and you don't want your user to be able to go back to login screen by pressing back button.